# Checking if user has process running

Tags: shell, process, grep

I have been using this to check if the process i want to edit is already running.

Now this returns if any user has this process running, but since multiple users now run it, i need this line to only return true if the current user has it running. I already have something to execute something as_user and the username is saved in ME.

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i SCREEN | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$LOGNAME` provides the current user name. So in case you are using the command to run from X user and want to check for that specific user process, then you can add additional grep for `$LOGNAME`. I am using SUSE-Linux. In case you are using any other OS, Please specify.